# CICD Pipeline with Codebuild is not allowing the Node JS application to create new directory in the tests

Tags: node.js, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am building a Node JS application. I am building the CICD Pipeline for my application using AWS Codepipeline and AWS Codebuild integrating those two together.

But I am now having a problem running the tests that involve creating a new directory or file because the application does not create a new directory or file in the Codebuild as the tests are run in the Codebuild. My tests are invoking the following function to create new directories.

```
const createDirectoryForFileIfNotExists = (directory) => {
  if (! directory) {
    return;
  }
  let segments = directory.split("/");
  if (segments.length < 1) {
    return;
  }
  let checkDirectory = "";
  for (let i= 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    if (checkDirectory == "") {
      checkDirectory = segments[i];
    } else {
      checkDirectory = checkDirectory + "/" + segments[i];
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(checkDirectory)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(checkDirectory);
    }
  }
}
```

But when the tests are run in the Codebuild, I am getting the following error.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
```

But it is perfectly fine when I run the tests on the server or locally. A parameter passed to the function is this.

```
/codebuild/output/src120020864/src/test_storage/payment-proof
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Won't fix your issue, but passing `{recurse: true}` as a second argument will automatically create the parent directories and alleviate the need for your function